# Querying Google calendar for unused appointment slots?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, google-calendar-api

Anyone know how to query Google calendar for unused appointment slots?

Using Google sheets, I'm trying to query my calendar to list all appointment slots that are open. Since the script below didn't work, apparently they're not stored as calendar events until they're utilized. Can anyone offer suggestions? Ideally there's a way to query just for unused appointment slots. Thanks in advance for any help.

*[Posts about this topic from a few years ago said Google didn't support it. I'm hoping that's changed.]*

```
function getCalendarEvents() {
  // Get the active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  // Clear the existing content
  sheet.clear();
  
  // Set the headers
  sheet.appendRow(['Event Title', 'Start Time', 'End Time']);
  
  // Get the current date and time
  var now = new Date();
  
  // Calculate the date 3 weeks from now
  var threeWeeksFromNow = new Date(now.getTime() + 3 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  
  // Fetch the calendar events between now and three weeks from now
  var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(now, threeWeeksFromNow);
  
  // Loop through each event and write it to the sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];
    sheet.appendRow([event.getTitle(), event.getStartTime(), event.getEndTime()]);
  }
}
```

Comment: How big are your appoint slots? What's the earliest? What's the latest?

Comment: Hi Cooper, thanks for your response. The slots range from 30 minutes to 2 hours. Earliest are 9am, latest ones end at 4pm.

Comment: So if you allocate in 30 minute increments you can have a maximum of 14 time slots. And with 2 hours you could get as little as 3 a day

Answer (score 0):

**Finding unused appointment slots**

They are the ones that don't have anything in them except for the time frame of the appointment.

The function to start it all going is on the bottom because it's that last one that I wrote.  It's called `findEmptySlotsForWeekOf` and it requires a date.  I prefer to use the date constructor new Date(4digityear,month - 1,date,9,00) where the 9 is the start time of the first appointment it will only find events that are within the range of 0900 to 1600 because that's what you requested.  The first thing it does is to figure out the date of monday for the week of your date and then it's currently setup to display 14 days.  When it finds a match it append `\nEvent Title`.  You can add whatever else you wish.

You will need to add the calendar id's of all of the calendars you wish to use they're all in an array in `findEmptySlotsForWeekOf`.  You will also have to assign it a sheet name to display all of the data and you do that on the fourth line of the same function.

```
function makeSlots(dt = new Date()) {
  const stDate = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate() - dt.getDay() + 1);
  //Logger.log([...new Array(7).keys()])
  const tWeek = [...new Array(14).keys()].map(k => Utilities.formatDate(new Date(stDate.getFullYear(), stDate.getMonth(), stDate.getDate() + k), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy"));
  //Logger.log(tWeek);
  let o = tWeek.reduce((a, d, i) => {
    a.headers.push(d);
    let t = d.split('/');
    a.year = t[2];
    a.month = t[0];
    a.day = t[1];
    a.hour = a.start;
    a.days.slots = [...new Array(timeDiffInMinutes(9, 16) / a.incr).keys()].map(idx => {
      return [`${slotdata(new Date(a.year, a.month - 1, a.day, a.hour, 0, 0), idx * a.incr).string}`];
    });
    return a;
  }, { headers: [], start: 9, end: 16, incr: 30, days: {} });
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
  return o;
}
function createSlotTemplate(dt = new Date(), name = "Sheet0") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(name);
  sh.clearContents();
  const tObj = makeSlots(dt);
  let o = tObj.headers.forEach((h, i) => {
    let s = tObj.days.slots.slice();
    s.unshift([h]);
    sh.getRange(1, 1 + i, s.length, s[0].length).setValues(s);
    sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, s[0].length).setNumberFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
  });
  return tObj;
}
function timeDiffInMinutes(StartHour, EndHour) {
  const dt = new Date();
  const Start = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate(), StartHour, 0, 0);
  const End = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate(), EndHour, 0, 0);
  var second = 1000;
  var minute = 60 * second;
  var hour = minute * 60;
  var day = hour * 24;
  var t1 = new Date(Start).valueOf();
  var t2 = new Date(End).valueOf();
  var d = t2 - t1;
  var days = Math.floor(d / day);
  var hours = Math.floor(d % day / hour);
  var minutes = Math.floor(d % day % hour / minute);
  var seconds = Math.floor(d % day % hour % minute / second);
  return d / minute;
}

function slotdata(datetime, minutes) {
  let dt = new Date(datetime);
  let e1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dt.valueOf() + minutes * 60000), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm")
  let e2 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dt.valueOf() + (minutes - 1) * 60000 + 30 * 60000), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm");
  return { begin: dt, end: new Date(dt.valueOf() + minutes * 60 * 1000), string: `${e1}-${e2}` };
}

function findEmptySlotsForWeekOf(adate = new Date(2023, 7, 12, 9, 0, 0)) {
  const idA = ["an array of calendar ids"];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const evObj = {};
  const tObj = createSlotTemplate(adate, sh.getName());
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const [ds, ...ts] = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const col = ds.reduce((a, h, i) => { a[h] = i + 1; return a; }, {})
  idA.forEach(id => {
    let cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id);
    ds.forEach(da => {
      let t = da.split('/')
      let year = t[2];
      let mon = t[0];
      let day = t[1];
      let daystart = new Date(year, mon - 1, day, tObj.start, 0, 0);
      let dayend = new Date(year, mon - 1, day, tObj.end, 0, 0);
      let evs = cal.getEvents(daystart, dayend);
      evs.forEach(ev => {
        let evSlotCells = [];
        let evStartTime = ev.getStartTime();
        let evTitle = ev.getTitle();
        let evEndTime = ev.getEndTime();
        let evStartTimeValue = evStartTime.valueOf();
        let evEndTimeValue = evEndTime.valueOf();
        let dts = Utilities.formatDate(evStartTime, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
        let idx = ds.indexOf(dts);
        if (~idx) {
          sh.getRange(2, col[dts], tObj.days.slots.length).getDisplayValues().flat().forEach((s, i) => {
            let t = s.split('-');
            let st = t[0].split(':')
            let e = t[1].split(':')
            let slotStartValue = new Date(year, mon - 1, day, st[0], st[1]).valueOf();
            let slotEndValue = new Date(year, mon - 1, day, e[0], e[1]).valueOf();
            if (evSlotCells.length == 0 && evStartTimeValue <= slotEndValue) {
              evSlotCells.push(sh.getRange(i + 2, col[dts]).getA1Notation());
            } else if (evSlotCells.length > 0 && evEndTimeValue > slotEndValue) {
              evSlotCells.push(sh.getRange(i + 2, col[dts]).getA1Notation());
            }
          })
          if (evSlotCells.length > 0)
            sh.getRangeList(evSlotCells).getRanges().forEach(r => {
              r.setValue(`${r.getDisplayValue()}\n${evTitle}`);
            });
        }
      })
    })
  })
}
```