# How to receive correct available dates in Google calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

I wrote a code to check the google calendar of my employees and to provide a available start and end  date / time for the requested time.
But when I do so, it do not show a 100% correct result. In most time (I tried different things) it shows a slot during another event. Or for example I tried to integrate the working hours, so that it checks from 8am to 5pm... and then it always said, that no event is available...

This is the last version of my code.
Can you have a look and help me with a suggestion?

````
function getAvailability(email, minutes) {
  if (!email) {
    throw new Error('Die E-Mail-Adresse ist erforderlich.');
  }
  if (!minutes) {
    throw new Error('Die Dauer in Minuten ist erforderlich.');
  }

  var calendar;
  try {
    calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(email);
    if (!calendar) {
      throw new Error('Kalender nicht gefunden oder Zugriff verweigert für: ' + email);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Fehler beim Abrufen des Kalenders: ' + e.message);
    throw e;
  }

  var now = new Date();
  var twoWeeksFromNow = new Date(now.getTime() + (14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var events = calendar.getEvents(now, twoWeeksFromNow);

  for (var i = 0; i < events.length - 1; i++) {
    var currentEvent = events[i];
    var nextEvent = events[i + 1];

    if (currentEvent.isAllDayEvent()) {
      continue;
    }
    
    var currentEventEnd = currentEvent.getEndTime();
    var nextEventStart = nextEvent.getStartTime();

    if ((nextEventStart - currentEventEnd) >= (minutes * 60 * 1000)) {
      return {
        'start': currentEventEnd,
        'end': new Date(currentEventEnd.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000))
      };
    }
  }

  var lastEventEnd = events[events.length - 1].getEndTime();
  if ((twoWeeksFromNow - lastEventEnd) >= (minutes * 60 * 1000)) {
    return {
      'start': lastEventEnd,
      'end': new Date(lastEventEnd.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000))
    };
  }

  return null;
}

function doGet(e) {
  // Logge die eingehenden Parameter für die Anfrage
  console.log("Received parameters:", e.parameters);

  try {
    var email = e.parameter['Bearbeiter-Mail'];
    var minutes = parseInt(e.parameter['Dauer-Minuten'], 10);

    // Überprüfe, ob die Parameter vorhanden und gültig sind
    if (!email) {
      throw new Error('Die E-Mail-Adresse ist erforderlich.');
    }
    if (isNaN(minutes)) {
      throw new Error('Die Dauer in Minuten muss eine gültige Zahl sein.');
    }

    // Führe die Hauptfunktionalität aus
    var availability = getAvailability(email, minutes);

    // Logge die ermittelte Verfügbarkeit
    if (availability) {
      console.log("Verfügbarkeit gefunden:", availability);
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(availability))
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    } else {
      console.log("Keine Verfügbarkeit gefunden.");
      return ContentService.createTextOutput('Keine Verfügbarkeit gefunden')
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Logge und gebe Fehler zurück
    console.error("Error:", error);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'error': error.message }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}```




The goal is to send the calender email adress + meeting time in meetings to the api and then receive a feedback, when the person is available. (The api process works).. The problem I have is just in the way how the calendar is checkt. It does not work correctly.
````

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided, a few things could be causing incorrect availability results:

The code is assuming back-to-back events without gaps. So if there is a 30 minute gap between two 1-hour meetings, it may show that slot as unavailable. You would need to check if the gap is larger than the requested meeting duration.
The code is not taking into account things like calendar working hours restrictions. So it may show availability outside of normal working times. You would need to add logic to respect calendar hours of operation.
Recurring events or all-day events may not be handled properly and could show as available incorrectly. Additional logic would be needed to process those correctly.
To address these issues:

Check gaps between events versus meeting duration
Add calendar hours of operation restrictions
Handle recurring and all-day events properly
Additionally, rather than get availability by scanning all events, you could use the FreeBusy API

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback!

I have updated the code but it still finds always the same available slot. It feels like the system is not checking if there is an event / meeting where I am invited and where I did not agree for example

Comment: Do you have any further idea on this?

Comment: I use this code to find empty slots on my calandars: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77269837/7215091

Comment: Thanks a lot! Here I recorded a short video to explain the problem in detail: https://www.loom.com/share/5bd6fa31e7674248b1f8bc1bcc52a430

Thanks a lot for your ideas